# Error placement in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, errorplacement

I want to place the validation error in specific location, by default I am using

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element){               
            error.insertAfter(element);     
        }
```

This display the error message just after the form control element. But I want to display the error in specific location for each form control element.

My **HTML** page is look like this:

```
<form method='post' action='regaction.php' id='regform'>
    <label for='username'>Username<span class='required'>*</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type='text' id='username' name='username'><br><span class='err_label'></span><br>
    <label for='password'>Password<span class='required'>*</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type='password' id='password' name='password'><br><span class='err_label'></span><br>
    <label for='password'>Confirm Password<span class='required'>*</span> </label>
    <input type='password' id='cpassword' name='cpassword'><br><span class='err_label'></span><br>
    <label for='email'>Email<span class='required'>*</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <input type='text' id='email' name='email'><br><span class='err_label'></span><br>
    <input type='reset' name='resetbtn' id='resetbtn' value='Reset'>
    <input type='submit' name='submitbtn' id='submitbtn' value='Register'>
   </form>
```

I want to display the validation error message in `span` with `class` `err_label` for each form control.

I tried something like this:

```
$(element).next().find('.err_label').html(error);
```

and

```
$(element).find('.err_label').html(error);
```

etc..

but no luck. I think the problem may be simple but I can't get the correct solution.. someone can help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {              
    $(element).nextAll('.err_label').eq(0).html(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add

```
errorElement: 'span', 
errorClass: 'err_label'
```

into your validate() call.

Comment: this override the `span  with class error`, now my form contain two `span with class err_label` for each control element.